# How to use Windows Python install in MSYS2

Tags: python, mingw, msys2

I am using MSYS2 as my terminal in Visual Studio Code for GCC support and to use a few tools that are easier to build often in a Linux environment. However, I would like to install Python on Windows and use that instead of Python packaged with MSYS2. My current workaround is to define the following alias in my `.bashrc`:

```
alias python='$PYTHONPATH/../../python.exe'
alias pip='$PYTHONPATH/../../pip.exe'
```

I recently tried using venv and that is causing problems as when I type `python` from the MINGW terminal, it points to my Windows python instead of the venv python. This is not a bug obviously, but I need a way to use Windows python instead of MSYS2 python for packages like numpy, tox, matplotlib, etc. because the MSYS2 packages for those are a headache and currently, tox+pytest in MSYS2 does not work. At this time, my solution above works for everything I've thrown at it in Python.

So, my question is how do I use my Windows Python install instead of the POSIX/Windows MSYS2 Python without the above hack? Is there a way I can define the `PATH` to include my Windows Python as the first entries in MSYS2 `PATH`?

Here is what it looks like right now:

```
$echo $PATH
/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/c/Users/Glen.Nicholls/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Scripts:/c/Users/Glen.Nicholls/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37
```

I would like to know how to make it the following instead, delete python from MSYS2, or find another way to accomplish this.

```
/c/Users/Glen.Nicholls/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Scripts:/c/Users/Glen.Nicholls/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:...
```

Answer (score 7):

You have to put the path for `/c/Users/Glen.Nicholls/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37` and `/c/Users/Glen.Nicholls/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Scripts` before those on the msys2, right? Then I wouldn't try to use the terminal as it's too tricky, so, I will use the control panel to do it more easily. Here are some screenshots how I will do that for you.

(Sorry that I couldn't put the pictures, but the links for them instead, I couldn't put any pictures as I am a new member. Also, sorry I made the instructions too detailed.)

First, open search box with `Windows`+`S` key.
[image: picture1]

Then, choose the environment variables options from the window.[image: picture2]

Then, choose the PATH system variable at the bottom section, and choose `edit` (the upper is the user `PATH`, and the bottom is the system `PATH`) [image: picture3]

This is how it looked before:-- [image: picture4]

Then, choose C:/Users/Glen.Nicholls/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37 and click “Move Up” until done. Likewise, do it same with “C:/Users/Glen.Nicholls/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Scripts” until it's on the top.[image: picture5]

This is how it looks now:-- [image: picture6]

After you are done, restart your terminal and hopefully, it will work. :D